# How to use this nmp module: read-excel-file in electron.js

Tags: reactjs, electron

My purpose is to open an xls file to collect data and put it in an array. I have tried to find an example to see how it could be done in Electron.js, has anyone done this previously, is it possible? Any better idea something simple without getting too complicated?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help you https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/master/demos/electron

Comment: thanks. I have cloned this project to look at it in detail. It is possible that I can take ideas.

Comment: every knowledge we are sharing na, happy coding :)